# HTML / CSS image resize proportion

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I want linked images to have the size 800x600 with the original proportions. The linked images could have the site 1000x400 or for example 600x1000.

At this time I resize the image with width=800px and in the class div overflow is hidden

```
<div class="cut">
<img src="www.example.de/image" width=800px>
</div>
```

This works when the image proportion is like 600x1000, but not when it is 1000x400.
How does it handle every image size?

Comment: You want to force both sizes without altering the ratio? That's not possible.

Comment: Tip: `800px` work only  in CSS, use without `px` in `width="..."` html attribute or use CSS: `.cut img { width: 800px; }`

Comment: I tested it here and it works as you are expecting it. There is probably some problem with your CSS somewhere else.

Comment: My problem is, that a image with 1000x400 will be resized to 800x320, but I want 800x600. A crop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an easier solution, change the image to background.

Like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/yp7jq0tf/

```
.image{
  float:left;
  width:800px;
  height:600px;
  border:1px red solid;
  background:no-repeat center center;
  background-size:100%;
}
```

Html part:

```
<div class="image" style="background-image:url(       
   http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png 
);"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
.image{
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
    background:no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You will need to crop the images somehow, so putting them in the background makes most sense.

http://jsfiddle.net/x07jbku2/